# Is it possible to restore the source code (Models, Controllers) of an application, from the files on the website (when Publish has been used)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been working on a MVC 3 application on my laptop, which now has crashed. I have uploaded the newest edition of the site through the "Publish" method in VS2010. Is it possible to retrive the source code of the application? Because i cant see the Models or Controllers on the FTP.

Thanks

Comment: This is why you should use a SCM tool.

Comment: Ouch, hate to hear that. I started to use SVN about a year ago and it is a must have for any developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a decompiler before to get back source code from a compiled website.

It doesnt give you the files all nicely ready to start developing again, it is a bit pain staking going through the decompiler and getting all the code you need out.  But it can be done.

I cant remember which one i used, im sure a quick google will give you loads to choose from.  I think there might even be one shipped with vs.

Comment: .NET Reflector does the job. Thx.